# How to migrate from @clr/icons to @clr/core?

Tags: vmware-clarity

[Clarity changelog](https://clarity.design/news/3.0.0) for version 3 says package @clr/icons is now deprecated.

> Deprecating the @clr/icons package as a standalone package. A
> migration path will be available to get improvements made in Clarity
> Core initative to optimize build sizes.

But [documentation for icons](https://clarity.design/icons/get-started) still uses deprecated package in examples of code.

How I can migrate on @clr/core package?

**angular.json**

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/@clr/icons/clr-icons.min.css"
]
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import '@clr/icons';
import '@clr/icons/shapes/essential-shapes';
import '@clr/icons/shapes/media-shapes';
import '@clr/icons/shapes/social-shapes';
import '@clr/icons/shapes/travel-shapes';
import '@clr/icons/shapes/technology-shapes';
import '@clr/icons/shapes/chart-shapes';
```

Comment: Have you tried using running `ng update @clr/angular` I thought it would take care of it

Comment: No, I didn't use `ng update`. I will try this command during next update, thanks for advice.